# Automatically Send Invoice

Tags: civievent, civimember, contributions, invoice

I am wanting to send a VAT receipt invoice when a contribution is added.  To include all the invoice details that show in contribution invoice that's available for printing or emailing.  Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At administer - civicontribute - civicontribute component settings, there's a checkbox down in the invoicing section to include it automatically.

Comment: thank you so much.  I couldn't see that for looking!